# Problem with access to control properties in Multibox

Tags: asp.net, javascript, mootools

I used  multibox-component to create lightbox-similar div. But I faced problem. I placed textbox with id ‘tbx_position’ in that div. I entered some symbols in textbox and then tried to read value via javascript-function (it had to alert document.getElementById(‘tbx_position’).value). Every time that value was empty.

There is [example](http://chukcha002-2.hosting.parking.ru/) of it.

Furthermore, if I place in the div asp:Button, server OnClick-eventhandler doesn’t catch fire.
Is any idea, what’s reason? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `<form>` & `</form>` tags to your page.